# How to take multiple screenshots of one URL using phantomjs and without reloading the page?

Tags: url, phantomjs, screenshot

What I want to be able to do is to change the width and height of an iframe at each loop interaction and then take a screenshot.. all this without calling page.open over and over again.. it takes time and it's inefficient..